# WHY cant I pin an email from the search results?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-365

Im on O365 and using the outlook web UI on chrome on Mac

When browsing emails in my inbox I can pin them by clicking the little pin icon they all have on them (I use the feature quite a bit):

[image]

Pretty obviously use case here, I want to search for an email and pin it.
Well when I search for an email, the emails that appear dont have the pin! This is what I see:

[image]

They have no pin icon, and when I pop them out I see no options to pin them. It seems the only way to pin an email is with the pin icon.

This is so stupid and painful, is there a way to pin emails from the search results? What ive been doing is forwarding them to myself and then pinning those forwarded emails which feels idiotic

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests, there is no  pin options when you scan emails in the search results and I'm afraid that this is by design. If you would still like the feature you mentioned, it is suggested to submit your feedback via [Outlook UserVoice](https://outlook.uservoice.com/).